# Is it possible to save changes in Firebug locally?

Tags: html, css, firebug, savechanges

What I'm trying to do is to save the changes I make to CSS and HTML on different sites with Firebug.

Just to be clear, I **don't** expect Firebug to upload the changes to the server via FTP or anything. I just want to save the changes locally, so only I will be able to see them.

For example I've seen a few Firefox/Chrome extensions that add a download button under every video on Youtube, so I know it's possible to do that somehow.

If you have a different way to achieve what I'm trying to do, I'll be glad to hear about it.

(It doesn't have to be with Firebug.)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to be able to change the page localy and have those changes "persist" when you later load the same page wihtout having to make any changes on the server, like when you use flash or adblocker and tell it to always remove some content from the page whenewer you load it.

Comment: this addon works only on firefox? is there any addon for chrome ?

Comment: cssUpdater, can save changes from css files locally and from FTp also.
[http://www.cssupdater.com](http://www.cssupdater.com)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try using [Greasemonkey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greasemonkey).

It has support for adding custom scripts that are run whenever you load a page (linked to which pages it should load on) and that can make changes to the page dynamically.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/

Comment: Wow, thanks! that's pretty much what I was looking for, thanks again mate

Answer (score 5):

If you don't mind using [Web Developer Toolbar](https://addons.mozilla.org/sv-se/firefox/addon/60/) it's easy to save changes made to the DOM (and CSS).

When you install the toolbar, you'll get a "View Source" menu, click on that and choose "View generated source". Then just copy and paste that into a .html file.

You did not say if you alter your HTML or CSS, if CSS, [FireFile](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/52365/) is a very good addon for this.

Edit, with some Googling, i found [FireDiff](http://www.incaseofstairs.com/firediff/), which states that it can export changes made in Firebug, i have not tested it bit it's worth checking out.

Comment: i tried the Web Developer Toolbar, i changed the DOM, but when i refresh the page the changes arent saved...

Comment: No, the changes aren't saved when you reload the page. You need to write those changes to disk manually.

Comment: Oh, then thanks, but this isnt what im looking for. Im looking for an extension that will let me save changes that i made, and only i will be able to see them.

Comment: Alright. Firebug does not provide a way to save the tree. Have you tried FireDiff or FireFile?

Comment: Yea i used FireDiff but its still not what im looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The http://chrispederick.com/work/web-developer/ web developer toolbar will let you add a user style sheet to a site which should achieve your goals.

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not be exactly what you're asking for, but you can download the extension FireDiff in order to save changes made with FireBug. I made a little tutorial on how to do it here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m4OmZLX2zd4

Answer (score 0):

I have a somewhat simlar use-case that I solved differently.  I'm not sure if it is what you are looking for or not. I'll describe the behavior and if that is helpful I'll explain exactly how I implemented it.

I changed the code that execute when you click "Run" (or Ctrl+Enter) to check to see if the first line of the code is a hard-coded string `//LoadFromFile:<file path>`. If it is, and the file exists then I pull the file off of the local file system and run it instead of executing the code in the console window. This way I can use an external text editor to write code.